# pagination wordpress с выводом по кастомным таксономиям

Tags: wordpress, url, get, pagination

имею такой запрос:

```
 $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'=>1,
            'paged' => ( get_query_var('page') ? get_query_var('page') : 1 ),
            'post_type' => array('post-pressa','post-metro','post'),
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'items',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => array( $term )
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => array( $city )
                ),
            )
        );

$query = new WP_Query($args);
$max_num_pages = $query->max_num_pages;
```

вывожу пагинацию

```
<?php
        global $wp_query;
        $big = 999999999; 
        $page_args = array(
            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format' => '?page=%#%',
            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('page') ),
            'total' => $max_num_pages

        );

        ?>


        <?php echo paginate_links($page_args) ?>
```

ссылки страниц получаются такими www.mysite.ru/my_posts/page/2
и по этой ссылке страница отдает 404 ошибку

если вручную вписать www.mysite.ru/my_posts?page=2 все работает корректно
в админке вордпреса "permalinks" стоят произвольные ссылки.

Пробовал по разному в том числе и вариант когда `format' => ''`

Вопрос в том  как заставить пагинацию работать, либо нормально читать /page/2 , либо отдавать ?page=2 но не в ущерб работе других путей по сайту

Comment: Посмотрите как настроена переадресация для постраничной навигации в global $wp_rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Незнаю на сколько это было верно, но я решил проблему написав свой кусок сборки пагинации

```
<div class="pagenavi">
    <?php
    $term = get_query_var('term'); //echo $term;
    $tax = get_query_var('taxonomy'); //echo $tax;
    $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
    if($max_num_pages>1){?>
        <?php
        for($i=1;$i<=$max_num_pages;$i++){?>
            <?php  if($i==1){?>
                <a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/<?php echo $tax;?>/<?php echo $term;?>?<?='id='. $city; ?>" <?php echo ($paged==$i)? 'class="selected"':'';?>><?php echo $i;?></a>

            <?php }else{?>
            <a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/<?php echo $tax;?>/<?php echo $term;?>?<?php echo 'page=' . $i; ?>&<?='id='. $city; ?>" <?php echo ($paged==$i)? 'class="selected"':'';?>><?php echo $i;?></a>
        <?php   } ?>

    <?php }
    } ?>
```